# How to return Http error response from webViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()?

Tags: android, ajax, webview, http-headers, webviewclient

I've override `public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView webView, String url)` and it should return custom response on request from `Ajax` function. But looks like `WebResourceResponse` contains only response body. How can I pass HTTP response like this one :

```
HTTP/1.1 202
Cache-Control: no-cache
Custom-param: param
```

to my `WebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Android API 21 [WebResourceResponse.html#setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html#setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase(int,%20java.lang.String)) and [WebResourceResponse.html#setResponseHeaders()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html#setResponseHeaders(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)) methods are available.